# How to send Hashtable through TCP?

Tags: c#, tcp, hashtable, tcpclient

To send string I use `StreamWriter` but how I can send `Hashtable`? Or its not possible?

```
public static Hashtable Users = new Hashtable(15)
```

Note: I didn't find anything to try so I don't have any code with what I tried.

Comment: This question ahs been answered here before, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413828/how-to-serialize-hashtable-in-c-sharp 
or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918187/xml-serialization-of-hash-tablec3-0

Comment: If you are using TCP, why would you be using StreamWriter? (which is a TextWriter)

Comment: I used this project http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial239_Csharp-Chat-Part-1---Building-the-Chat-Client.html

Comment: Is there any reason it needs to be `Hashtable`? because ultimately the question of "can I serialize this" depends a lot on "what is in there?" - could it be a `Dictionary<somthing,somethingelse>` ? that would a: work better with more serializers, and b: allow us to answer the question

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't mind to change it to Dictionary

Comment: @Loclip so: what is in there? what is the dictionary *of* ?

Comment: @MarcGravell its `TcpClient` and `String` which TcpClient its tcp of user and string his username

Comment: @Loclip you certainly can't serialize a `TcpClient`; that makes no sense.

Comment: @MarcGravell can I pass somehow TcpClient array?

Comment: @Loclip you can't; that makes no sense; a TcpClient encapsulates one end of a socket; you can't send a socket. Send data; not implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) to serialize any [serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) object:

```
BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
binaryFormatter.Serialize(streamWriter.BaseStream, Users);
```

Comment: should be a stream, not a streamWriter

Comment: can you serialize an object implementing IDictionary with a binary serializer?

Comment: @daryal `BinaryFormatter` doesn't care about interfaces; it is a type/field-level serializer. You are thinking of XmlSerializer. That said, I can think of many reasons not to use `BinaryFormatter`, too ;p

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialise it first and then send the serialised stream. There are lots of resources on serialisation both on this site and Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the `HashTable`  and deserialize it. But there is a problem, 
`HashTable` implements `IDictionary` interface they are not directly serializable. You can find an alternate way to serialize it in the following [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam/archive/2010/09/10/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-c.aspx).

Comment: that relates specifically to XmlSerializer; that is not the most common choice of serializer for writing to a raw socket